# SQLite on Android and MongoDB with synchronization

Tags: android, mongodb, sqlite, synchronization, nosql

Is it possible to use SQLite on Android and a NoSQL database like MongoDB on the server, with 2-way data replication/synchronization between the two?  Or is it best to either use SQL on both ends, or NoSQL on both ends, but not mixed?

Comment: 2-way data replication/sychronization between disparate databases (eg. SQLite and MongoDB) is likely a solution you would have to develop yourself.  What is your actual use case for data to sync?  Full 2-way replication would require some form of conflict resolution if the same data changes on both Android and server.  Perhaps you are thinking of a caching strategy where users can make changes/queries on their Android device while offline, and then sync data with the server when back online?

Comment: Yes, initially it'll be a caching strategy between a singe device and the server where data can only be modified on the device, not the server.  So, essentially, the server would be a backup. Eventually, I'll want to sync multiple devices that can all access and modify shared data.  That's probably when conflict resolution will become critical.  Considering Martin Fowler's Event Sourcing pattern.  Never having attempted this sort of thing before, I was concerned about potential problems arising from the SQL -> NoSQL mismatch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few different approaches to consider:

1) Use a database product that implements multi-master or MVCC (Multiversion Concurrency Control) *and* runs on both Android + your server.  There are some examples on the [MVCC wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control), with CouchDB being a common solution.  There is a [TouchDB-Android](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/TouchDB-Android) port which is optimized to run on Android and supports replication to CouchDB.

2) Your requirements may be simple (or unique) enough to warrant rolling your own solution.  A common solution would be using SQLite on Android and syncing information to a remote server over a (probably RESTful) API.

It is not essential to use the same database solution on both mobile device and server, but using a similar schema and query language will probably keep you saner.

Comment: Would also be worth looking into [PouchDB](http://pouchdb.com/) which is a JavaScript library implementing the CouchDB API.  PouchDB is designed to save changes while internet access is offline and later sync those with a CouchDB server when online.  Currently (May, 2013) this is still at a "alpha preview" release level, but the general approach is very promising.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at [SymmetricDS](http://www.jumpmind.com/), I haven't used it myself but I'm considering it.

It currently allows a SQLite DB on Android to sync to a mongoDB backend but currently not in the other direction. Apparently you could create the necessary sync data into the intermediary sync'ing DB for it to work back to your SQLite DB.

There is also an iOS version in the pipeline.

It has a GPL licence so you'll need to pay (unless your app is open source) if you use it commercially.