# How to make an android app work in offline mode in android

Tags: android, mongodb, data-synchronization

I want to know how i can make my app work in offline mode and store the data on a local database on the android device.

I am using mongodb database and fetching the data by using JSON Parsing.

What should i use to make my app run in offline mode and also update the changes made on the server ?

Which tools should i use ,also which is the best and easy method to implement this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to do two things: (1) monitor connectivity changes (easy); and (2) architect a way to store pending operations to disk, as well as read those operations from disk and process them when you regain connectivity (not so easy). The topic is rather broad and I doubt anyone is going to provide you with a significant amount of code, so perhaps you should try building something yourself and come back with more specific questions as you come across problems in your approach.

Comment: @Karakuri..Thanks Can u tell this which approach i should use for this so that i should start it..i am bit confused..

Comment: You should look at "Firebase". I just stumbled onto it from stackoverflow yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

1. first you create local SQLite Date Base
2. in that create one extra column like "noNet" ...
3. In this column you save your data when phone in offline mode and then send data to web server when phone is online

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit older now, but I'd like to add what I believe is a good architecture approach to solving this.

Take a look at the tech talk given by Yigit and Adam at the Android Dev summit.  https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/3C4GPowmWLb

Seems the core components are:

- Job Scheduler/Queue, via https://github.com/yigit/android-priority-jobqueue
- DBFlow to make interaction with the SQLite database easier: https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow
- And an EventBus https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus to easily broadcast when the actual jobs complete (so the UI and other components can be notified).

Those 3 together get you most of what you will probably need.  Their tech talk (first link above) really details these things better, and there's a final example application you can take a look at as well:  https://github.com/yigit/dev-summit-architecture-demo

Answer (score 0):

If you have an option, you can go for couchdb or couchbase which provide couchlite for android and sync is taken care by itself.

you can also refer this thread here [SQLite on Android and MongoDB with synchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295960/sqlite-on-android-and-mongodb-with-synchronization)